# How can I create categories with different options of it in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to design a database in MySQL about categories with options for categories.

Example : Script classified ..

When you want to add ads into the "cars category" you must add some options for this car,but when you add ads in "Apartments for sale category" you must add some options for this Apartment, for example, this image from Dubizzle site illustrates for classified.

When you want to add a car in "cars category", you will show these options

[image]

and when you want to add ads in "Apartments for sale category"
you will show these options:

[image]

How can I design the database as such?

```
categories and sub-categories with different options for any categories
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table category
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    catName varchar(100) not null
);

create table catOption
(   -- no attempt to share option across multiple categories
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    catId int not null,
    descr varchar(100) not null,
    listingOrder int not null   -- order listed on screen

    -- include FK into category
);

create table listing
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    catId int not null,
    title varchar(100) not null,
    verbeage text,
    price decimal(12,0) not null

    -- include FK into category
);

create table listOptions
(   -- this table houses a particular listing options (answers if you will)
    -- programmer chooses whether or not to save 'blanks'
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    listingId int not null,
    optionId int not null,
    answer varchar(100) not null    -- you choose datatype
    -- include FK into listing
    -- include FK into catOption
);
```

> The FOREIGN KEY constraint is used to prevent actions that would
>   destroy links between tables.
>
> The FOREIGN KEY constraint also prevents invalid data from being
>   inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the
>   values contained in the table it points to.

Comment: where's the options table for categories ?

Comment: Rename subCat to options

Comment: what do you mean about "FK" ?

Comment: Foreign Key constraints

Answer (score 1):

## Categories

First, you need to define your categories table, like **categories(id, name, description)**

## Control Types

As we have seen from the pictures that you have shared, sometimes you have a set of checkboxes, sometimes you have dropdown options, etc. To support this, you need a table like **control_types(id, name, description)**. In your application you will know by the control type value what control needs to be used and how the selections should be understood.

## Controls

Now, you can create your controls, like this: **controls(id, control_type_id, title)**. Note that we do not have a `category_id` in this table, because we want to be able to support the possibility of reusing some controls in multiple categories as long as they are compatible with those. For instance, the `price` control that you have is needed for both categories. So it is not enough to assume that each control is linked to a single category, quite the contrary, a category can have multiple controls and a control might belong to multiple categories.

## Controls of Categories

To achieve the many-to-many relation described in the previous chapter, we create a table where we store the pairs: **controls_of_categories(id, category_id, control_id)**.

## Control Items

It's nice that we have the controls, but sometimes they are not trivial. Sometimes we need to select a single value from some options (dropdown) or, we might need to be able to select several options at the same time (checkboxes). To achieve this, we will need another table, like this: **control_items(id, control_id, label, value)**.

Comment: I'm the same person but I cannot comment on that account. In this way, we need to create a lot of tables, May there is simpler way from this

Comment: @Taha there are many simpler ways, but simpler is not necessary better. I recommend the creation of 5 tables, it's a one-time job to do and then you can implement the features you need. If you simplify the solution, you will likely no longer be in normal form and due to the inner intricacies of your data and problem-space your future self will likely have to rethink your approach if your overly simplify. So, while it is normal to want a simple solution, you need to think through what needs to be represented and which table seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Taha kindly read about database normalization, to fix issues due to data-redundancy and inconsistency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I found another way but it looks more complex so I'll use your method, Thanks

Comment: @Taha happy to help!

Comment: You did not mention how to do it in the ads table itself who must contain the options.

Comment: @Taha indeed, my answer was mainly focusing on the categorization of ads and it did not address the ad tables, thanks for the observation. There are several possible solutions. A simple solution would be to have a category_id field in the ads table and then a single category would be supported. A less simple, but better solution would be to have an ad_categories(id, ad_id, category_id) table, that would have records that would represent that an ad has a category. This latter approach would support the case when an ad has multiple categories.

Comment: @Taha another issue to deal with is to store multiple selections for ads based on control_items. This can be achieved by the creation of an ad_items table, whose each record would represent an item of a specific ad, having an ad_id foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

**Category_sub_category_tab:**

```
CId PK
,CName Text
,SubCatId FK(Category_sub_category_tab(CId))
```

**Options**:

```
ID PK
,OName Text
,CID FK(Category_sub_category_tab(CId))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It a dynamic scheme , first you have to define your categories , controls (text, drop-down ,etc) then you have to define categoryFields this will contian categoryId, field info.. , and you have to define field values table for type drop-down and stuff like that